# Error when I try to install keras on R (devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")

Tags: r, keras

I am fairly new to R, so I apologize if my question is trivial. 
I try to install keras on R (version 3.4.1). I installed package devtools, but when I download keras with

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
```

I get the next error:

```
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/keras@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/keras/zipball/master
Installing keras
Warning message in utils::untar(src, exdir = target, compressed = 
"gzip"): 
“‘/bin/gtar -xf '/tmp/RtmppsizUk/R6_2.2.2.tar.gz' -C 
'/tmp/RtmppsizUk/devtools58a921ad859f'’ 
returned error code 127”Installation failed: error in running
command
Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/tensorflow@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/tensorflow/zipball
/master
Installing tensorflow
Warning message in utils::untar(src, exdir = target, compressed = 

"gzip"):
“‘/bin/gtar -xf '/tmp/RtmppsizUk/processx_3.1.0.tar.gz' -C 
'/tmp/RtmppsizUk/devtools58a939032642'’ returned error code 
127”Installation failed: error in running command

Warning message in utils::untar(src, exdir = target, compressed = 
"gzip"):

“‘/bin/gtar -xf '/tmp/RtmppsizUk/yaml_2.1.19.tar.gz' -C 
'/tmp/RtmppsizUk/devtools58a949f478b4'’ returned error code 
127”Installation failed: error in running command

'/home/valeriya/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file 
--no-environ  \

--no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  '/tmp/RtmppsizUk/devtools58a913225b77/rstudio-tensorflow-d6df08f'\
  --library='/home/valeriya/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/R/library'  \
  --install-tests 

Installation failed: Command failed (1)
'/home/valeriya/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file 
--no-environ  \

 --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \

'/tmp/RtmppsizUk/devtools58a95a711ad4/rstudio-keras-900088e'  \

--library='/home/valeriya/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/R/library'  \

 --install-tests 


Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

When I try to install it via

```
install.packages("keras")
```

I get the next warning message:

```
also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘testthat’, ‘processx’,     
‘tensorflow’

Warning message in install.packages("keras"):
“installation of package ‘cli’ had non-zero exit status”Warning 
message in install.packages("keras"):
“installation of package ‘testthat’ had non-zero exit status”Warning 
message in install.packages("keras"):
“installation of package ‘processx’ had non-zero exit status”Warning 
message in install.packages("keras"):
“installation of package ‘tensorflow’ had non-zero exit 
status”Warning message in install.packages("keras"):
“installation of package ‘keras’ had non-zero exit status”Updating 
HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

After that loading keras via

```
library('keras')
```

gives

```
Error in library("keras"): there is no package called ‘keras’
Traceback:

1. library("keras")
2. stop(txt, domain = NA)
```

How can I fix it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the CRAN version first ? `install.packages("keras")`

Comment: @kluu, when I try to do so I get the long warning message (I will add it to the question), and then loading keras via 'library('keras')' does not work.

Comment: hmm...do you have tensorflow and keras installed for Python ?

Comment: @kluu yes, I have. If it could help, I use ipython notebook with R kernel.

Comment: ok...i'm trying to reproduce the error on a new VM. Can you try running the same commands in a R console ?

Comment: @kluu it works from R console! Thank you very much! However, now I have an error  'failed to parse CPython sys.version: '2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]' after installing some python packages with 'install_keras()'. Probably the problem is because I already have python 2 and python 3. Anyway, it seems that my problem solved. Thank you again!

Comment: Cool, glad it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

**RStudio** has an excellent TensorFlow with R walkthrough on its website! Check out the full documentation for installation and usage [here](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/keras/).

To install Keras for R:

`devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")`

Then, after you've used `devtools` to clone `rstudio/keras` from GitHub:

`library(keras)
install_keras()`